# "Unknown column" error using the same table twice in JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    z.id,users.name,e.name,tt.date,
    CASE WHEN z.priority = 6 THEN 'Mayor' WHEN z.priority = 5 THEN 'Muy urgente' 
    WHEN z.priority = 4 THEN 'Urgente'WHEN z.priority = 3 THEN 'Mediana' 
    WHEN z.priority = 2 THEN 'Baja' WHEN z.priority =1 THEN 'Muy baja'  END,
    ROUND(SUM(tt.actiontime/3600),2) AS HORAS, c.name, i.name, 
    glpi_tickets_users.type 
FROM glpi_tickettasks tt 
INNER JOIN glpi_tickets z ON tt.tickets_id = z.id 
LEFT JOIN glpi_itilcategories i ON z.itilcategories_id = i.id 
INNER JOIN glpi_users AS users  ON users.id = tt.users_id 
INNER JOIN glpi_users AS req  ON req.id = glpi_tickets_users.users_id 
LEFT JOIN glpi_usercategories c ON c.id = users.usercategories_id 
INNER JOIN glpi_entities e ON z.entities_id = e.id
WHERE  tt.date>'2016-01-06'   and tt.date<'2016-01-06' 
GROUP  BY tt.users_id,tt.id  
ORDER BY users.name limit 5
```

It outputs the following error:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'glpi_tickets_users.type'
>   in 'field list'

I need to use the table `glpi_users` twice to get "user type".

What's wrong with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not joined table glpi_tickets_users in your query so far.

```
SELECT z.id,users.name,e.name,tt.date,CASE WHEN z.priority = 6 THEN 'Mayor' WHEN z.priority = 5 THEN 'Muy urgente' WHEN z.priority = 4 THEN 'Urgente'WHEN z.priority = 3 THEN 'Mediana' WHEN z.priority = 2 THEN 'Baja' WHEN z.priority =1 THEN 'Muy baja'  END,ROUND(SUM(tt.actiontime/3600),2) AS HORAS,c.name,i.name,glpi_tickets_users.type 
FROM glpi_tickettasks tt 
INNER JOIN glpi_tickets z ON tt.tickets_id = z.id 
LEFT JOIN glpi_itilcategories i ON z.itilcategories_id = i.id 
INNER JOIN glpi_users AS users  ON users.id = tt.users_id 
/**here is the join to glpi_tickets_users **/
INNER JOIN glpi_tickets_users ON users.id = glpi_tickets_users.users_id
INNER JOIN glpi_users AS req  ON req.id = glpi_tickets_users.users_id 
LEFT JOIN glpi_usercategories c ON c.id = u.usercategories_id 
INNER JOIN glpi_entities e ON z.entities_id = e.id
WHERE  tt.date>'2016-01-06'   and tt.date<'2016-01-06'  GROUP  BY tt.users_id,tt.id  ORDER BY users.name limit 5
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because no where in your query you are listing the table `glpi_tickets_users`. Neither in `from` clause nor in any on the `join` clauses. If you don't want that column `glpi_tickets_users.type` then simply remove it from your query and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the data structure of your tables, but isn't the type column on the glpi_users table?

If that's the case, replace `glpi_tickets_users.type` with `glpi_users.type`

The final query will be this:

```sql
SELECT z.id,users.name,e.name,tt.date,CASE WHEN z.priority = 6 THEN 'Mayor' WHEN z.priority = 5 THEN 'Muy urgente' WHEN z.priority = 4 THEN 'Urgente'WHEN z.priority = 3 THEN 'Mediana' WHEN z.priority = 2 THEN 'Baja' WHEN z.priority =1 THEN 'Muy baja'  END,ROUND(SUM(tt.actiontime/3600),2) AS HORAS,c.name,i.name,glpi_users.type

FROM glpi_tickettasks tt

INNER JOIN glpi_tickets z ON tt.tickets_id = z.id

LEFT JOIN glpi_itilcategories i ON z.itilcategories_id = i.id

INNER JOIN glpi_users AS users  ON users.id = tt.users_id

INNER JOIN glpi_users AS req  ON req.id = glpi_tickets_users.users_id

LEFT JOIN glpi_usercategories c ON c.id = u.usercategories_id

INNER JOIN glpi_entities e ON z.entities_id = e.id  

WHERE  tt.date>'2016-01-06'   and tt.date<'2016-01-06'  GROUP  BY tt.users_id,tt.id  ORDER BY users.name limit 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not JOINING table *glpi_tickets_users* in your query at all, so you can't select from it. You need to modify your query to include *glpi_tickets_users*.